# Google App Engine - Can I have www.domain.com point to version X and beta.domain.com point to version Y?

Tags: google-app-engine

In google app engine can I have www.domain.com point to version X of my app, and beta.domain.com point to version Y?

If so, how could I do this?

Comment: please star this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently supported. Non-default versions are only accessible as appspot subdomains.

Comment: is there an open issue for this request? I searched through the database, but couldn't find any reference.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=1&q=custom+domain

Answer (score 0):

I have my domain hosted at 1and1.com and redirects subdomains to different versions in appengine.

www.example.com goes to the main version
beta.example.com goes to a beta version

You will need to do this through a third-party DNS

Comment: This is doing HTTP-level redirection, right? The appspot URL will show in the browser? (Otherwise this seems to conflict with Nick's accepted answer)